# incompatible type Piece can not convert into mouselistener in java

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I am facing problem , i have class Piece extends from JButton and i have Promote function in Piece class in that function i am adding mouse listener and i am getting this error ,

```
incompatible type Piece can not convert into mouselistener
```

here is promote function

```
public void promote()
{

                   pawnPromotion.setTitle("Pawn Promotion interface");
                   pawnPromotion.setSize(new  Dimension(400, 200));
                   pawnPromotion.setResizable(false);
                   JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 5)); 
                   final Piece king = new King(this.getBoard().getPieceToMove().isWhite(),this.getBoard().getboard());
                   final Piece queen = new Queen(this.getBoard().getPieceToMove().isWhite(),this.getBoard().getboard());
                   final Piece bishop = new Bishop(this.getBoard().getPieceToMove().isWhite(),this.getBoard().getboard());
                   final Piece knight = new Knight(this.getBoard().getPieceToMove().isWhite(),this.getBoard().getboard());
                   final Piece rook = new Rook(this.getBoard().getPieceToMove().isWhite(),this.getBoard().getboard());
                   addMouseListnerq(this, queen);
                   addMouseListnerq(this, bishop);
                   addMouseListnerq(this, knight);
                   addMouseListnerq(this, rook);
                   mainpanel.add(king);
                   mainpanel.add(queen);
                   mainpanel.add(bishop);
                   mainpanel.add(knight);
                   mainpanel.add(rook);
                   pawnPromotion.add(mainpanel);
                   Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                   pawnPromotion.setLocation(dim.width/2-pawnPromotion.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-pawnPromotion.getSize().height/2);
                   pawnPromotion.show();

}
```

and this  is code for add mouse listner function

```
public void addMouseListnerq(final Piece ClickedPiece,final Piece impPiece)
{

    impPiece.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                       Piece piece = new Piece(null);
                       if(impPiece instanceof Queen) piece = new Queen(getBoard().getPieceToMove().isWhite(),getBoard().getboard());
                       if(impPiece instanceof Bishop) piece = new Bishop(getBoard().getPieceToMove().isWhite(),getBoard().getboard());
                       if(impPiece instanceof Knight) piece = new Knight(getBoard().getPieceToMove().isWhite(),getBoard().getboard());
                       if(impPiece instanceof Rook) piece = new Rook(getBoard().getPieceToMove().isWhite(),getBoard().getboard());
                       piece.setBackground(ClickedPiece.getOldBackgroundColor());
                       piece.setOldBackgroundColor(ClickedPiece.getOldBackgroundColor());
                       addMouseListener(piece);
                       if(ClickedPiece.HasPiece()) getBoard().kill(ClickedPiece, getBoard().getPieceToMove(), getBoard().getAllSquares());
                       else getBoard().move(ClickedPiece, getBoard().getPieceToMove(), getBoard().getAllSquares());
                       int indextofPawn =0;
                       indextofPawn = getBoard().getAllSquares().indexOf(getBoard().getPieceToMove());
                       getBoard().getAllSquares().remove(getBoard().getPieceToMove());
                       getBoard().getAllSquares().add(indextofPawn, piece);
                       getBoard().resetColors();
                       getBoard().updateGui();
                       getBoard().deSelect();
                       setSelected(false);
                       getBoard().setPieceToMove(null);
                       if(getBoard().isWhiteplayerturn())
                       { getBoard().setWhiteplayerturn(false); }
                      else
                        { getBoard().setWhiteplayerturn(true); }
                       pawnPromotion.hide();

                   }});

}
```

Comment: what's the type of Piece? How did you declared it?

Comment: Piece is class that is extends from JButton ,

Comment: why MouseListener for JButton, use ActionListener (Key & Mouse Events) or events from ButtonModel, use JToggleButton

Answer (score 1):

Method `addMouseListener` expects an object of type `MouseListener`

Remove `addMouseListener(piece);`

Or implement the interface `MouseListener` in the `Piece` class

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in this statement:

```
addMouseListener(piece);
```

Your piece doesnt implements MouseListener interface and to [addMouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29), you pass parameter of type MouseListener.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your MouseAdapter you add call addMouseListener(piece). And Piece is not a MouseListener, it is just a JButton, as you have said.